# MariaDB Service Availability

Tags: mariadb, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am currently confused whether or not MariaDB is still available as a service in the Swisscom AppCloud (Internal). I have been creating several MariaDB services in the Internal App Cloud during the last years.
I thought I could do it again last week, but MariaDB is simply absent from the list of services available as shown by running 
`cf marketplace -s mariadb`

> Service offering 'mariadb' not found.

The official documentation apparently says that MariaDB is still offered (https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mariadb.html)

What is the status of MariaDB? Is there an End of Support date defined for the legacy services?

Thanks a lot

Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: Please post questions regarding the internal usage of Cloud Foundry (iAPC) in the appropriate internal channels. Stackoverflow should be used for the Public AppCloud.

Comment: In the public Swisscom app cloud the service is called `mariadbent` in case this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all available services by typing:

`cf marketplace`

If the service is no longer listed there, it's currently not available.

In the (soon to be retired) Swisscom Public Application Cloud, they had renamed the service to `mariadbent` and you can find it by typing:

`cf marketplace -s mariadbent`